# In a Java Servlet how can I change the value of an existing cookie?

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

In a Java Servlet how can I change the value of an existing cookie? There is an addCookie method, but no deleteCookie or editCookie in HttpServletResponse

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Those indeed don't exist. Just create utility methods yourself which do that. Particularly getting the desired cookie is quite bloated. E.g.

```
public final class Servlets {

    private Servlets() {}

    public static Cookie getCookie(HttpServletRequest request, String name) {
        if (request.getCookies() != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
                if (cookie.getName().equals(name)) {
                    return cookie;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

To edit a cookie, set its value and then add it to the response:

```
Cookie cookie = Servlets.getCookie(request, "foo");

if (cookie != null) {
    cookie.setValue(newValue);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

Set if necessary the maxage, path and domain as well if they differs from your default. The client namely doesn't send this information back.

To delete a cookie, set the max age to `0` (and preferably also the value to `null`):

```
Cookie cookie = Servlets.getCookie(request, "foo");

if (cookie != null) {
    cookie.setMaxAge(0);
    cookie.setValue(null);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

Set if necessary the path and domain as well if they differs from your default. The client namely doesn't send this information back.

Comment: if you get the cookie, set it, then get it again, do you get the old cookie or the new one?

Comment: @Sam: It within the same request, you get of course the old one. The set cookie is only available in the subsequent request because this information is passed through HTTP headers.

Comment: @BalusC Do you know if setting cookie values this way works with redirects? It seems as though the change is ignored, or rather, not propogated on the the header representation of the cookie. In my case, the cookie remains intact at the recipient end of the redirect. Appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Given my comment/ question above, I think the answer is to manage the cookies via a filter on the recipient side of the redirect. That is, remove the cookie in a filter before it hits the target jsp (using HttpServletRequestWrapper to manipulate cookies). Will report back findings.

Comment: @BalusC, how do you modify the value of an existing cookie obtained through `response.getHeaders(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE)` of a response object?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example from kodejava:

```
 public class ReadCookieExample extends HttpServlet {
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response)         throws    ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        writer.println("Name: " + cookies[i].getName() + "; Value: "                    +                   cookies[i].getValue());            
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws    ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}
```

}

That will get the cookies list, get the one you want and instead of printing out values, do something similar to this:

```
 cookie.setValue(String.valueOf(<new Value>));  
 cookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365);   
 cookie.setPath("/");   
 response.addCookie(cookie);  etc...
```

HTH,

James