# How to get cookies from a given path in JAVA?

Tags: jsp, cookies, aem

How can we get cookies from a given path? When we do request.getCookies(), by default it extracts cookies from "\". but if I want to get it from a given path suppose "\bin\test". In this case what should we do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1st question is are you able to get the request header stuffs? where even the cookie value for "\bin\test" is being sent over to your jsp file?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to roll your own filter of cookies by path

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html?is-external=true#getCookies()
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html
[In a Java Servlet how can I change the value of an existing cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447478/in-a-java-servlet-how-can-i-change-the-value-of-an-existing-cookie)

```
List<Cookie> getCookiesFromPath(@Nonnull SlingHttpServletRequest request, String path) {
    Cookie[] allCookies = request.getCookies();

    if (path == null || path.isEmpty()) { // convert cookie array to cookie list
        return Arrays.asList(allCookies);
    }

    List<Cookie> cookieList = new ArrayList<Cookie>();
    for (Cookie c :  allCookies) {
        if (c.getPath().equals(path)) { // or equals()
            cookieList.add(c);
        }
    }
    return cookieList;
}
```