# What to do if cookie already exists?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, cookies

In my application I have a dropdownlist and when the user clicks on an item is redirects them to a certain page. In this servlet I create a cookie with there selected item which contains the value of the drop-down list(So when they return the the previous page that item will be selected in the drop-down list)

What I want to know different values may be selected at different times it there a way to modify the cookie for that drop-down list or do I have to create a new one each time. I cant see that as being a sustainable way of doing it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447478/in-a-java-servlet-how-can-i-change-the-value-of-an-existing-cookie

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the cookie by getting it from the request and assigning the new value:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
Cookie dropDownCookie = null;
for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
    if(cookie.getName().equals("DROP_DOWN_COOKIE")){
        dropDownCookie = cookie;
    }
}
if(dropDownCookie!=null){
    dropDownCookie.setValue("THE NEW VALUE");
    response.addCookie(dropDownCookie);
}
```