# Not able to override the cookie in browser on each service request and response

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt

Not able to override the cookie value for each response in the browser. I have a scenario like I will make multiple requests on each page. I m setting a new cookie in each response. it is taking the cookie from the first response. but not able to replace cookie for the corresponding responses. I found some related topics but didn't help for my scenario. Need to override the cookie for each service response in the browser. the below code will run for every request and add it in every response.
**Note:** Cookie is overriding on page load or if it is refreshed, for Ajax calls only it's not overriding.
is there any option using javascript to get the latest cookies?

```
String token = jwtTokenService.generateToken(user); 
Cookie authCookie =  new Cookie("Token", token);
        authCookie.setHttpOnly(false); 
        authCookie.setSecure(true); 
        authCookie.setMaxAge(3600); 
        authCookie.setPath("/"); 
response.addCookie(authCookie);
```

Sorry folks finally I found the issue, since the response is overriding with  spring rest service response I am not able to get the latest cookie thanks

Comment: Above code only adds a new cookie to the response. Where is your code to override the cookie value? And what do you want tot override?

Comment: updated plz check and let me know for any info.

Comment: Check here on how to override cookie value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447478/in-a-java-servlet-how-can-i-change-the-value-of-an-existing-cookie

Comment: @Vel: I tried this but no luck, I m not reloading the page per every request this might be a problem? :(

Comment: Are you making asynchronous requests to the server? Show us your client side code.

Comment: @Vel: yes making asynchronous calls, from client side we are not doing anything just taking that cookie value.

Answer (score -1):

Cookie is getting updated in browser, Just checked it. Below is the code which I added in JSP page to check if content of cookie is getting updated:

```
String token = "User: "+(new Date()).toGMTString();
Cookie authCookie =  new Cookie("Token", token);
    authCookie.setHttpOnly(true); 
    authCookie.setSecure(true); 
    authCookie.setMaxAge(3600); 
    authCookie.setPath("/SampleTest");
    authCookie.setDomain("SampleTest");
    response.addCookie(authCookie);
```

Please recheck properly

Comment: Please provide comments before downvoting, everyone is here to help

Comment: Anyway this is not working for me and I am using the HTML not JSP

Comment: Browser overwrites the existing cookie received from same domain if a new cookie is received, so technically cookie should be replaced with newer cookie, that is what I explained that, I wrote a JSP to test that cookie was getting updated.